# Syntax for a regex for numbers prefixed by a particular string

Tags: javascript, regex

I really didn't want to ask this here as I'm sure this will get me downvoted, but I truly am stuck.

I have used multiple tools to test regex expressions but the syntax is very confusing.

**What I have tried**

I am going to be using javascript for this, I have the following string for example:

```
Product ID: 4381 - Fanta Berry cans 355ml x 24
```

This is a search result from an autocomplete dropdown, it will always have the format:

```
Product ID: product_id - Product Name
```

Now I need to get the product_id the number between the :  and  -

I have tried

```
/[\d]/g
```

But that simply selects all the numbers in the string.

I also tried:

```
[(:\b)-]
```

And that selects the : and - which are the characters between the number I want to get. But I can't seem to figure out the syntax to get the number between them. I feel like I'm very close but after hours of searching I can't seem to crack it, I know this isn't a place for people to do the work for you, but I assure you I have tried and am really at a loss! If anyone can tell me the little bit of syntax that's missing to get that number I would be very appreciative.

Comment: You could try it like this `^[^:]+:[ \t]*(\d+)` using a capturing group https://regex101.com/r/yNY78Z/1 or more precise `^Product ID: (\d+) -`

Comment: `str.match(/Product ID: (\d{1,4}) -/)[1]`

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to resort to parsing the string in orde to get the product id back?

Comment: You can match it with `/\d+/` fine, i.e. `string.match( /\d+/ )[ 0 ]`. (Also, remember that if you don't use the "global" flag it will only match the first result.)

Comment: PS: It may be "yet another simple regex problem", but your question includes signs of effort (attempts, which make me believe you actually spent time on this, before asking), so i don't see a reason to downvote. I only dislike it, when people's decision flowchart has the first arrow from "start" to "ask SO". Helping people, who are actually stuck, after trying, is exactly, what SO is for.

Comment: These are both great answers guys but they are selecting the words product ID: when I test them, I just need the numbers. It would appear the two answers below are brilliant as well. @YannickK That's a good idea why didn't I realise that!

Comment: @YannickK if you post your answer as an actual answer I will mark it as the correct one as it is the simplest and cleanest answer here in my opinion. If you don't want to submit it as an answer I will choose Pavel's answer instead.

Comment: @DinleyHob Sure, will do, then we can finalise the question.

Comment: In regex, capture groups (brackets) are used to get specific parts of a match as separate strings. Without a global flag, `String.prototype.match` returns the same structure as [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description). Therefore, these capture groups are accessible on the result with `[1]`, `[2]`, ... (depending on how many there are). If there is no match, the entire result will be `null` (a check for this helps prevent unhandled exceptions, when something goes wrong).

Comment: Oh very good to know, I have done some regex research, but I don't use it all that often. So this is the first time iv'e had to do it.

Comment: Many regex here have a full match which includes things like "Product ID: ", but only care about a capture group inside, which is only the digits (notice the brackets around the digit selectors, e.g. `(\d{1,4})` (one to four digits) or `(\d+)` (at least one digit, no upper limit).

Comment: Or perhaps split the string on a space and take the second part if `"Product ID:` is hardcoded and there are always digit following.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `/\d+/` just fine:

```js
const string = "Product ID: 4381 - Fanta Berry cans 355ml x 24";
const match = string.match( /\d+/ )[0];

console.log( match );
```

Just make sure to select the first element of the resulting array.

Also note that not using the global flag will have the RegEx only match the first result

Comment: Good show! You have imparted wisdom for which I shall be forever grateful. Regex is a nightmare in terms of syntax but like anything it'll just require some practice. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=(Product ID: ))(\d*)
```

Mind that this method is support by most, [but not every](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) browser.

Comment: I'm not sure why use a positive lookbehind here instead of simply a non-capturing group. Or even no group at all.

Comment: This worked well and supports in chrome which is the browser we use at work! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the product id prefix:

```
/Product ID: (\d+)/g
```

Here's full JavaScript code for you so that you don't get confused:

```js
var str = "Product ID: 4381 - Fanta Berry cans 355ml x 24";
var ret = str.match(/Product ID: (\d+)/);
var product_id = ret[1];

console.log(product_id);
```

Comment: This also works perfectly well as well, however I am going to have to say Yannick K answer is the most simple and effective. Only she did not post an answer just a comment.